# Save android Data permanently Even Clear Data

Tags: android

Is there any way to save data from an Android app which is only delete after uninstall but will not deleted after clear data.
I save data in file and database but both has been deleted after clear data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I save data in file and database but both has been deleted after clear data

Whenever you save your data in to file it would not delete even you clear the data or unistall the app until you delete the file. so save your data in file.